# Copy/paste data validation in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I feel a bit silly not being able to figure this out. So this is the data validation I have set up:

Cell Range: Journal!J2

Criteria: List from a range - Journal!W2:X2

Cell Range: Journal!M2

Criteria: List from a range - Journal!Y2:AA2

This is great in my first row. I create another row and I'd like it to update all of the '2' to '3'. The cell range updates correctly, but the criteria does not, and I can't figure out an easy solution other than going in and updating it manually.

I've tried copy/paste as well as paste special -> data validation.

I know something like $Y$2 would fix the row/col but that's the opposite of what I want. I guess I'm wanting to maintain the relative formula vs it being an absolute formula?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, the "list from a range" type of validation treats the reference to the list as absolute rather than relative. I know two workarounds:

#### Custom formula

Validation based on the custom formula

```
=not(isna(match(J2, W2:X2, 0)))
```

is equivalent to "value must be from the range W2:X2", and it will be copied down correctly, the reference to W2:X2 being relative.

*Drawback*: you don't get an in-cell dropdown list with custom formula validation.

#### Script

One can use an [Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) to manage data validation rules.  The following script sets data validation rules in each cell of the range J2:J100, where the value is required to be from W:X of the same row.

```
function validate() {    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("J2:J100");
  var valuesColumn = 23;  // begins in W 
  var valuesLength = 2;   // has length 2, so W:X
  var firstRow = range.getRow();
  for (var i = 0; i < range.getHeight(); i++) {
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
               .requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, valuesColumn, 1, valuesLength), true)
               .setAllowInvalid(false)
               .build();
    range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh awesome! I've been working on some other custom scripts anyway, and couldn't figure out how to set a validation rule that way. I'll totally try this out later tonight. Thanks!